# How to upload image if field name is logo[0][image]

Tags: php, ajax, file-upload

I have a form with multiple file upload fields. The fields are dynamic so I have added file name with a format like `logo[0][image], logo[1][image]...`

Now I am using ajax to upload my image for each field. But when I use the file name like `$_FILES['logo[0][image]']`, it shows me error of undefined index for `logo[0][image]`.
How can I solve this issue? How can I upload files with field name like this?

Here is how my `var_dump($_FILES)` looks like,

```
array (size=1)
  'logo' => 
    array (size=5)
      'name' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => 
            array (size=1)
              'image' => string 'image.png' (length=9)
      'type' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => 
            array (size=1)
              'image' => string 'image/png' (length=9)
      'tmp_name' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => 
            array (size=1)
              'image' => string '/tmp/phppBdjky' (length=14)
      'error' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => 
            array (size=1)
              'image' => int 0
      'size' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => 
            array (size=1)
              'image' => int 2604
```

Comment: Can you give an example of how the form looks like? Also what does `var_dump` `$_FILES` tell you?

Comment: hello @apokryfos, I have updated my post with requested data.

Comment: You'd probably need something like `$_FILES['logo']['name'][0]` to get the equivalent of the name of the `logo[0]` upload. It will get complicated fast, you might want to consider simplifying your form that uploads these things